# Finding unmatched records using pig script

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, sqoop

In My POC, am trying to implement an ETL data flow (star schema) using pig script, As you all know before loading in to fact table i would like to load dimension. Here in dimension i need to load only the new records from source(csv file), I mean records which is not there in dimension(sql server). All joins(skewed,replicate & merge join) in pig are trying to match the existing records and produce only matched records. Can you please tell me how to bring the unmatched record as an output in order to load in to my dimension?

Thanks
Selvam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a left outer join of source (csv file) with that of dimension(sql server) table. Resultant records that have the join column as null are the new records. Then filter out records whose value of the join column is null.

Comment: Thanks Hussain:-) I tried left outer am getting the below error

Comment: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias Y. Backend error : Scalar has more than one row in the output.

Comment: When you refer columns from the joined relation use "::" operator to resolve the column instead of using "." eg. JOIN_RELATION::col_name   read https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2134 for details

Comment: Thanks Hussain, It worked for me with your help:-) One more questions, Is it possible to create surrogate key using pig ? If yes can you please let me know the logic ? Thanks

Comment: @user3350280 Sorry I could not get your question. Do you mean you want to create a key in other datasource using Pig ? . Please accept my answer if it solves the question that you had asked.